# R - Relevance of comparison calculation

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, vectorization

**Hi there!**

I have a table with 24 names and their score. For me it is relevant to match two people with somewhat the same score. Therefore i need to calulate every players difference in score, compared to all other players. This should result in a 24x24 matrix where the score on either side of the diagonal are equal

**What I have**

```
 name1       score1
 name2       score2
 name3       score3
 .....       .....
name24      score24
```

**What I'm looking for**

```
                   name1             name2           name 3    ...          name 24
name1                  0     score2-score1    score3-score1    ...   score24-score1
name2      score1-score2             0        score3-score2    ...   score24-score2
name3      score1-score3     score2-score3                0    ...   score24-score3
...                  ...               ...               ...   ...              ...
name24    score1-score24    score2-score24   score3-score24    ...                0
```

Of course the absolute value of the numbers across the diagonal will be equal therefore it is only nessesay to calculate one half of the scores.

**Question**

Is there any easy way to do this kind of operation, preferebly a vectorized action, or do I have to build it with for-loops?

//HK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `outer` function is probably what you are looking for

```
score <- sample(24)
names(score) <- sprintf("Player%02i", 1:24)
outer(score, score, "-")

         Player01 Player02 Player03 Player04 Player05 Player06 Player07
Player01        0       19        4       18       10       17       21
Player02      -19        0      -15       -1       -9       -2        2
Player03       -4       15        0       14        6       13       17
Player04      -18        1      -14        0       -8       -1        3
Player05      -10        9       -6        8        0        7       11
Player06      -17        2      -13        1       -7        0        4
Player07      -21       -2      -17       -3      -11       -4        0
```

(Just showing the first columns and rows.)

Comment: Is there an easy way to keep the col/row names. All the names are the row-names of the score table?

Comment: Sure, but it is hard to tell what form your data is on from your question. Can you edit it and add the output of `dput(<your.data>)`?

Comment: Sorry i'm not by ny PC at the moment. But the data is in vector format, with row.names as the names of the players. If you need the output, i'll post it later. The name of the only column is 'total'..

Comment: A vector doesn't have columns or rownames so it would be good to get the `dput` output. I'm heading home for the day now though, but can look at it later.

Comment: is.vector(total)=TRUE - though

Comment: Really? Never seen that before. My point is, when you ask something on SO it is very hard to figure out details like this if you do not provide a sample of your data in the exact same form as you are using (usually done with the `dput` function). Guessing takes a lot of time for the answerer and rarely gets right.